# How to replace Ubuntu logos & brand-marks in custom distro?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, graphical-logo, branding, ubuntu

I was trying to create an ubuntu based distro in KDE and want to know that is there any way to replace kubuntu & ubuntu logos or brand marks ?

Like in kde startup menu has kubuntu's logo how can I replace all the similar logos?

And where all the logos are located in Ubuntu distro. 
Working on ubuntu & kubuntu 12.04.03

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/194062/how-can-i-replace-ubuntu-branding-with-my-own

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK after searching through the Linux file system, i found few files (logos) which can be replaced to prevent copyright violation.

All the files resides in

```
      /usr/share/icons &
      /usr/share/pixmaps
```

File names to replace are (All files are in png or svg file format)

```
   start-here 
   distributor-logo
   ubuntu-logo
```

I will add more names if i will find in future.
Also 
edit these files as per your requirements
              `/etc/issues.net`
          `/etc/lsb-release`
           `/etc/issue`

but then you have to edit `/usr/share/pyshared/aptsources/distro.py`

and assign values of original lsb-release file to variables like

```
       self.id="Ubuntu"
       self.codename="precise"
       self.description="Ubuntu 12.04.02 LTS"
       self.release= 12.04
```

Thanks.